# Best apps for chess openings

Tags: opening, preparation

Can you recommend best chess apps for preparing openings? It is weakest part of my game and soon I will be playing my first local chess turnament. It would meant a lot to me!

Also, can you give me some advice on how to prepare in general? Thanks.

Comment: [This question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18115/is-there-any-good-app-for-learning-openings) is a bit old but I think most of the apps mentioned there are still up. Does it answer your question?

Comment: If you are about to play your first tournament, there's a 99.9% chance that the opening phase is not the weakest part of your game.

Comment: I play a lot of blitz games online and openings are my weak spot. (I am 1850 at blitz and 1950 at bullet on chess.com). I often win in the endgame. But I get your point.